# Undo margin text changes in Scintilla

Tags: c#, undo, scintilla

I'm writing a text editor with Scintilla (actually ScintillaNET, but information on vanilla Scintilla could be useful as well).  In this editor, we're wanting to display change information in a margin (for instance, if I modify a line of text, that line would display my name in the margin).  I've managed to have the margin change on modifying a line, but I can't seem to figure out a good way to undo the margin change if someone undoes their change.

I've tried calling BeginUndoAction in the BeforeTextInsert event and EndUndoAction at the end of the TextInserted event, but that doesn't seem to treat the margin changes as undoable.  Is there a decent way to undo margin changes?  I'm thinking I may need to implement my own little margin undo stack (or modify Scintilla's undo stack) and just handle it that way, but if there's something built in, I'd rather go with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just went ahead and created my own undo stack to save margin changes.  If the text is being modified and it's not an undo, I add modified text, start position, line count and a list of strings (the margin text for each line modified).  If there's a modification and it is an undo, I peek at the first item on the stack and if the position and modified text is the same, I go ahead and change the margins back to the old values.

Seems to work ok, although it's a bit uglier than I'd like.  I do worry about the stack somehow getting out of sync with the Scintilla undo stack, but I'm not really wanting to modify the Scintilla source.